# I want to declare my variables in one place to not repeat the code, react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

My api fetch calls use the same headers, instead of repeating the variables for each api call function, can I place these variables in one place, then call those variables? I have tried putting them into a function then calling that function, but react complains the variables are missing. I am using a class component and I'm refering to the variables **parsed** and **headersAPI** being repeated, I want them in one place, ideally.

```
   componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserProfile();
    this.searchBands();
  }

  getUserProfile() {
    let parsed = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "access_token"
    );
    parsed = { token: parsed };
    console.log(parsed.token);

    let headersAPI = {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + parsed.token }
    };

    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, headersAPI)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          userName: data.display_name,
          log: console.log(data)
        })
      )
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({
          log: console.error("Error:", error),
          errorApi: true
        })
      );
  }

  searchBands(name) {
    let parsed = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "access_token"
    );
    parsed = { token: parsed };
    console.log(parsed.token);

    let headersAPI = {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + parsed.token }
    };
    let searchName = this.state.searchName === "" ? "The Cure" : name;

    //search band
    fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${searchName}&type=artist`,
      headersAPI
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          artistName: data.artists.items[0],
          log: console.log(data),
          image: data.artists.items[0].images[0].url
        })
      )
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({
          log: console.error("Error:", error),
          errorApi: true
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Make a method for fetching these or properties on the object that hold the values?

Comment: Make them properties of the object? `this.headers` or `this.parsed`?

Comment: can you show me please, I don't fully understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I just placed the variables outside the class declaration, then called them inside the api call functions, seemed to work.

```
const parsed = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("access_token");
const headersAPI = {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + parsed }
    };

    class App extends Component {..}
```